# PHP How to solve nested array values inside selectbox

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, nested

I want to show it like when I select an operator it should be listing all the states under operator_id  45 / 46 etc.

It is't using any data base.

But instead of "Insert Array" I want to insert my function, which creates an Array at the end. If I insert the Array, it says:

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [operator_id] => 45
            [company_id] => 1
            [company_name] => Aircel
            [operator_name] => Aircel
            [mode_name] => Normal
            [id_name] => Mobile/Phone Number
            [pattern] => ^([1-9][0-9]{9})$
            [min] => 1
            [max] => 9999
            [def] => 10 digit number
            [payment_type] => Prepaid
            [states] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [state_id] => 9
                            [state_code] => 4
                            [state_name] => karnataka
                        )
                      [1] => Array
                        (
                            [state_id] => 10
                            [state_code] => 5
                            [state_name] => andra pradesh
                        )

                )

            [cities] => Array
                (
                )

        )
[1] => Array
        (
            [operator_id] => 46
            [company_id] => 1
            [company_name] => *****
            [operator_name] => *****
            [mode_name] => Normal
            [id_name] => Mobile/Phone Number
            [pattern] => ^([1-9][0-9]{9})$
            [min] => 1
            [max] => 9999
            [def] => 10 digit number
            [payment_type] => Prepaid
            [states] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [state_id] => 3
                            [state_code] => 11
                            [state_name] => tamilnadu
                        )

                )

            [cities] => Array
                (
                )

        )
```

But instead of "Insert Array" I want to insert my function, which creates an

I tried

```
<select name="countrycode" class="form-control" required>
<option value="">Select Operator</option>
<?php                        
foreach ($arryOperators as $arryOperator) {
echo '<option value="'.$arryOperator['operator_id'].'">'.$arryOperator['operator_name'].'</option>';    
$states .= echo '<option value="'.$arryOperator['state_id'].'">'.$arryOperator['state_name'].'</option>';   

}
?>                            
</select>
```